# Regex for email pattern

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

We've noticed a strange email pattern at work for customer emails and want to check them out. Table is Customers

| email | fullname |
| --- | --- |
| johnsmith423129@gmail.com | John Smith |
| carygrant926815@gmail.com | Cary Grant |

How do we search for this string in BigQuery using Regex? Which is basically the fullname plus 6 random digits (I think I have this part: [0-9]{6}) plus the domain, which is gmail.

I'm not sure how to basically create a regex that accounts for the fullname plus random 6 digits plus the domain (gmail). Any help is appreciated!

Comment: so you have both email and fullname columns in your table and want to output only those records/rows where above described pattern is found? please confirm or clarify

Comment: I have the suspicious email and the fullname columns. And I wish to output only those emails that contain:
* the fullname
* the digit pattern (6 random digits)
* and the email domain (gmail.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below

```
select * 
from  your_table
where regexp_contains(lower(email), r'^' || replace(lower(fullname), ' ', '') || '\d{6}@gmail.com$')
```

Comment: This works as well. Upvoting this. Now I need to buy your book.

Comment: lol, first I need to write it :o) . but in reality my "book" is here on SO via 5,235 Answers I provided for BigQuery tag

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Thank you for everybody's help

`where email = concat(fullname, regexp_extract(email, '[0-9]{6}@gmail.com'))`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE email LIKE fullname + '%[0-9]@gmail.com'
```

Comment: quick update: this didn't work

Comment: No matching signature for operator + for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: INT64 + INT64; FLOAT64 + FLOAT64; NUMERIC + NUMERIC; BIGNUMERIC + BIGNUMERIC; DATE + INT64; INT64 + DATE; TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL; INTERVAL + TIMESTAMP; DATE + INTERVAL; INTERVAL + DATE; DATETIME + INTERVAL; INTERVAL + DATETIME; INTERVAL + INTERVAL at [3:18]

Comment: @JeremyC one of the arguments needs to be cast either fullname or email part try to use the cast method to correct it .. smtg like cast(field as int64)

Comment: No matching signature for operator + for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signatures: INT64 + INT64; FLOAT64 + FLOAT64; NUMERIC + NUMERIC; BIGNUMERIC + BIGNUMERIC; DATE + INT64; INT64 + DATE; TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL; INTERVAL + TIMESTAMP; DATE + INTERVAL; INTERVAL + DATE; DATETIME + INTERVAL; INTERVAL + DATETIME; INTERVAL + INTERVAL at [3:18]

still receiving the same error with combinations

Comment: even if i cast both as an INT64, then the like operator doesn't work